# How can I use the pflag with the shortflag?

Tags: go

I'm used `pflag` to parsing command line argument, but how can I use the shortflag and set the required argument or non-required argument?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/spf13/pflag"
    "os"
)

var (
    prometheus *string = pflag.String("p", "", "prometheus url")
    cluster    *string = pflag.String("c", "", "k8s cluster name")
    namespace  *string = pflag.String("n", "", "namespace")
    timeout *time.Duration = pflag.Duration("t", 30 * time.Second, "prometheus SQL timeout Duration")
)

func main(){
    pflag.Parse()
    if *cluster == "" {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage of %s:\n", os.Args[0])
        pflag.PrintDefaults()
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use both shorthand and long-form args, use the P variant:

```
pflag.StringP("longName","l","","desc")
```

As far as I know, pflag does not have the concept of a "required" arg. You can get the flag and test if it was set:

```
pflag.Lookup("name").Changed
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I modified looks like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/spf13/pflag"
    "os"
    "time"
)

var (
    prometheus *string        = pflag.StringP("prometheus","p", "", "prometheus url")
    cluster    *string        = pflag.StringP("cluster","c", "", "k8s cluster name")
    namespace  *string        = pflag.StringP("namespace","n", "", "namespace")
    timeout    *time.Duration = pflag.DurationP("timeout","t", 30*time.Second, "prometheus SQL timeout Duration")
)

func main() {
    pflag.Parse()
    if ! pflag.Lookup("cluster").Changed {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage of %s:\n", os.Args[0])
        pflag.PrintDefaults()
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(*prometheus, *cluster, *namespace, *timeout)
}
```